# Prove: $B(x,y)$ Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, solution-verification

> Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue integrable. Prove: $B(x,y)=f(x)\cdot g(y)$ lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2$

$f,g$ Lebesgue integrable $\iff$ $f,g$ are measurable and $\int |f|<\infty$ ,$\int |g|<\infty$

$$\int \int |fg|dxdy=\int|f|dx\int |g|dy=\|f\|_1\|g\|_1<\infty$$

Using Tonelli's theorem

Comment: Can you state the definition of B(x,y) clearly ?

Comment: If f and g are functions in x and y respectively then this is correct

Comment: Tonelli's theorem must be used?

Comment: There is no question here, just problem and the answer.

Comment: Why can Tonelli's theorem be used?